# Is there an R package that can infer a causal structure with a mix of discrete and continuous variables?

Tags: r, conditional-probability, causality

I have an observational dataset with a mixture of discrete and continuous variables. I'd like to infer a causal structure compatible with the data.

The [pcalg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pcalg) package for R can handle datasets with continuous, discrete, or binary variables but apparently not a mixture of such, unless one is willing to write a custom function for testing conditional independence between such variables (which I wouldn't know how to do).

Is there an R package that can infer a causal structure compatible with a dataset that has a mixture of discrete and continuous variables?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interesting in undirected conditional independence networks, you should try the package [`BDgraph`](https://pure.uva.nl/ws/files/22019968/1501.05108.pdf). They use a Bayesian approach for structure learning. The package has an option for estimating Gaussian Copula Graphical Models (GCGMs), which should be more than capable of handling mixed input types.

The authors are also approachable, I reached out to them for my master thesis a few years ago :)

---

In case you only have one, or a few discrete variables, you could also consider using [`rags2ridges`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rags2ridges/rags2ridges.pdf) for joint estimation of the precision matrices of each class. Their approach is based on Tikhonov regularized covariance matrix inversion. The fused version lets you do this joint estimation.

There are also various packages that do the same for the LASSO-based approach. Just Google for "R fused LASSO".